# Shebang in script to use virtualenv interpreter with web script in Apache

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a VPS.  I'm using SSH and I created a local install of Python 3.4.3, and then created a folder named PythonTest with mkdir.

I then used virtualenv PythonTest to create a virtual environment and the source  PythonTest/bin/activate.  Now I'm trying to figure out what the shebang line should be to use this virualenv.  I uploaded hello_world.py using the normal

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
```

shebang line.  This script works just fine.  Text of the script is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 print
 print "Hello world!"
```

The following are lines I've tried without success:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
 #!/usr/bin/env PythonTest
 #!/root/.local/bin/python3
```

I'm new to SSH and python and trying to figure out how to be able to upload and run scripts with modules installed only in the virtualenv / alternate install of Python 3.4.3.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the full path to the `python` binary inside the virtual environment.

Comment: Umm... That's not a valid Python 3 script. `print` is a function in Python 3.

Comment: If I delete everything but the shebang line, it still gives an Internal Server Error, so while that may be incorrect, I don't think it's getting to that before throwing the error.

Answer (score 3):

If you already sourced the activate script, you can use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

instead, which will grab the appropriate python from your `PATH`.

Comment: OK.  I changed it to that and it worked.  How can I check the version to make sure it's 3.4.3 and not 2.6?

Comment: Since you're already relying on needing to activate from a virtualenv, you could probably get away with assuming the user picked the right Python. That being said, you could probably change to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to at least make sure you're using the major version of Python you want.

Comment: I did change to #!/usr/bin/env python3 and it didn't work.  I changed it back to #!/usr/bin/evn python and used the following script to see version and it turned out 2.6.6 which is not the virtualenv version of 3.4.3
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

print
print "Hello world!<br>"
print(sys.version)

Comment: You'll definitely need to run the activate script first in your virtualenv…do you see your virtualenv name in your prompt when you run the script?

Comment: I've already run the activate.  When I cd $home (as root) I see the folder PythonTest there which I created and then used virtualenv to create the virtual environment

Comment: You have to run the activate script on every new shell (or you could add it to your `.bash_profile` if you want). One way to see if activate is…errm…active is to `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`; it should tell you the name of your virtualenv if it really has been loaded.

Comment: I did update the .bash_profile adding the following:

export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"